# Pandas Cumprod from a certain index level

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I am trying to work out the compounded returns for the SPY from select years using Pandas & Python for withdrawing backtesting for retirement. I am struggling to get the compounded returns as using the code below it is working out the returns in the wrong way (2022 to 1972) instead of 1972 to 2022. 1972 is index 49 and 2022 (index 0). Also, I have created a variable called "Duration" to work out the start and end date how would I input this into the pandas data frame so it compounds the money invested from the start to end date.

Thanks for your help in advance. Tried googling this but I couldn't find any answer or documentation which helped me.

```
 df["Equity Portfolio Value"] = df["Total Money Invested"] * (df["Return"] + 1).cumprod() -1
```

Below are the previous cells relevant to other cells just creating input variables and importing data.

```
rowindex = df.index[50]

df.loc[df.index[0:50], "Total Money Invested"] = Equity_Value
[print(df)][1]

print(df)
```

> 

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
import time
import requests
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from jupyterthemes import get_themes
import jupyterthemes as jt
from jupyterthemes.stylefx import set_nb_theme
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\robwo\Downloads\SPYhistory.xlsx')
Portfolio_Value = input("Please enter your Portfolio Value in $ ")
Portfolio_Value = float(Portfolio_Value)
Equity_Allocation = float(input("Please enter your equity allocation in %"))
Bond_Allocation = 100 - float(Equity_Allocation)
print(round(Equity_Allocation))
print(round(Bond_Allocation))
Equity_Value = float(Portfolio_Value) * float(Equity_Allocation)/100
Bond_Value = float(Portfolio_Value) * float(Bond_Allocation)/100

print(Equity_Value)
print(Bond_Value)

import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime(1971,1,1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2021,1,1)

print(start_date)
print(end_date)
df.loc[0:96]

print(df)

df.sort_index(axis=0)

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)

print(df)

rowindex = df.index[50]

df.loc[df.index[0:50], "Total Money Invested"] = Equity_Value

df["Equity Portfolio Value"] = df["Total Money Invested"] * (df["Return"] + 1).cumprod() -1

print(df)
```

print(df)
print("\n"+ "You'r portfolio value is $" + str(Portfolio_Value))

set_nb_theme("Chesterish")

Here is the SPY return data from the 1972 to 2021 as an example as I cannot upload the CSV to Stack overflow. Currently using the code above it is doing $8000 (Total Money Invested) * 2021 return (0.2871%) = 10295.8

2021    28.71%
2020    18.40%
2019    31.49%
2018    -4.38%
2017    21.83%
2016    11.96%
2015    1.38%
2014    13.69%
2013    32.39%
2012    16.00%
2011    2.11%
2010    15.06%
2009    26.46%
2008    -37.00%
2007    5.49%
2006    15.79%
2005    4.91%
2004    10.88%
2003    28.68%
2002    -22.10%
2001    -11.89%
2000    -9.10%
1999    21.04%
1998    28.58%
1997    33.36%
1996    22.96%
1995    37.58%
1994    1.32%
1993    10.08%
1992    7.62%
1991    30.47%
1990    -3.10%
1989    31.69%
1988    16.61%
1987    5.25%
1986    18.67%
1985    31.73%
1984    6.27%
1983    22.56%
1982    21.55%
1981    -4.91%
1980    32.42%
1979    18.44%
1978    6.56%
1977    -7.18%
1976    23.84%
1975    37.20%
1974    -26.47%
1973    -14.66%
1972    18.98%

Comment: Could you share your data?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler - I have included another cell that should be relevant other code is just importing data to the Pandas dataframe and creating a few variables. I attached an image of the dataframe output so this should help. I have tried inversing the df but its still starts the compound returns from Index 0 to Index 49 instead of from index 49 to 0.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see an image, but could you include a sample of data as text, not image? It's important to share a copy-pastable, runnable example including specific data, your current code (thanks!), and expected output itself - not just plain English descriptions of these.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Hello Peter, I have added my code to the post however I have now fixed the problem. df2 = df.loc[0:49] df2_sorted = df2.sort_values(by=["Year"], ascending = True).head() df2_sorted["Equity Portfolio Value"] = df2_sorted["Total Money Invested"] * (df2_sorted["Return"] + 1).cumprod()

print(df2_sorted). If you know any why I not use .loc method as I want to get a loop to find the worst performing years for the portfolio allocation over a set duration e.g worst 50 years for the portfolio.